# Python upgrade issue

Tags: python, upgrade, redhat

I'm using RedHat. I have upgraded Python to version 2.7. I still have v2.6 on my system. When I try to run v2.7, I get this error:

```
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug 26 2014, 14:23:55) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I don't know what this means or how I can set it: `Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]`. Can anyone explain how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you upgraded? Via yum? Also, try opening a new terminal, so you are sure the new options are loaded.

Comment: No, not via yum. This is my company's VM so even though I had sudo access, it kept on saying permission denied. Also I thought it was a bad idea to upgrade system wide since RedHat may break. So I just downloaded the tarbel, unpacked and created an alias in .bash_profile. And yes I did log out and ssh back in multiple times. So I guess the new options are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

The system python on RHEL cannot be changed without you experiencing alot of pain. If you've installed python side-by-side, then you can invoke python as python2.7.